# How to convert a Pandas series to a date object

Tags: python, pandas

[My data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFMs8.png)

[It's type is series[][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAWAQ.png)

[I tried this way to convert but it didnt work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5x8DL.png)

Comment: Please don't share images of code, share the code instead

Answer (score 0):

To convert pandas `series` to `dataframe`, you can put `column name` inside extra `list`, e.g,

```
df = metro[['start_time']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is correct for converting a series to datetime type in pandas 
when I tried

```
>>>df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0])
>>>df
           0
0 2018-01-01
1 2018-09-09
>>>type(df[0])
```

i got

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

try printing

```
dataframe.dtypes
```

then I got

```
>>> df.dtypes
0    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```